# jquery $.post not working in reload current page

Tags: jquery, post, reload, .post

I am trying to hide some data in a query string. I used the $.post method, but it is not working:

```
if (!isset($_POST['sw']) or !isset($_POST['sh']))  
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $.post("index.php",{ sw: $(window).width(), sh: $(window).height() } );
           </script>';
```

When I use window.location.reload, it works perfectly:

```
if (!isset($_GET['sw']) or !isset($_GET['sh']))
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href+="?sw="+$(window).width()+"&sh="+$(window).height();
       </script>';
```

Comment: do you get any errors while posting,this may happen it you haven't included jquery

Comment: i include last.js in main source. no error msg. both width and height hava value in firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That $.post method is an ajax request, it is probably doing exactly what it's supposed to do, which will not reload the page unless you are doing a server side redirect. If you want to replace the contents of the page with the response to that ajax call you could do something like this:

```
$.post("index.php",{ sw: $(window).width(), sh: $(window).height() } ).done(function(data){
   $('#my_target').html(data);
});
```

But you need will need to make sure your response data is formed in a way that makes sense to load it this way, either return an html fragment or encode an array to json or whatever makes sense for what you're trying to do.